# Jenkins pipelines, sh, quotes and spaces

Tags: bash, shell, string, jenkins

I am trying to setup `sh` command as part of my Jenkins pipeline. This command has one parameter where list of values is supplied. Those values have spaces in them.

I have tried so many things, arrays, escaping etc etc none worked.

Here is an example:

```
# In Jenkins task I configure env variable:
VALUE_LIST=("Value One" "Value Two" "Value Three")

# In pipeline:
...
sh "command --param ${env.VALUE_LIST[@]}"
...
```

**Please understand that this is only one of the ways I tried to make this work.**

I need the result command to look like:

```
command --param "Value One" "Value Two" "Value Three"
```

Best I could achieve was

```
command --param Value One Value Two Value Three
```

Which obviously does not work

Comment: What is your queston?

Comment: My question is, how do I create this command that will work as expected

Comment: have you tried single quotes `'`instead of double quotes?

Comment: Yes, I honestly tried pretty much anything I could find... `sh ' comand --param '"${env.VALUE_LIST[@]}` no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
printf "%s\0" "${VALUE_LIST[@]}" | xargs -0  sh -c 'command --param "$@"' command_name
```

Print the values to `xargs` and use null as delimiter. Then `xargs` calls `sh` and `sh` executes the command with the values as arguments. The last piece, `command_name`, will represent the command by the name you provide. It is obligatory in this construct, as otherwise command will not receive the first value form the list `"$@"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Full enough?

Comment: It did work as expected, but still didn't work in pipeline due to the command it self.. There is some bug in it, I reported it. Fortunately the command accepts parameters in different formats, one of which is JSON and I managed to get it work with that.